# Layout Props is missed in React Native View Component document

Tags: reactjs, react-native, document

I go to [React Native View Component online document](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#style), I see style property of View Component only accept View Style type. But I can use properties of Layout Props like padding, margin... for my View Component. Is that document missing or I just misunderstood?[image]

Comment: Hope you miss to read this part :) 

https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props

Comment: @codehesh  I read that part but I can't find padding, or margin in that props.  Can you say more about this?

Comment: Layout styles are common across all components, they probably didn't want to point out

Comment: @UğurEren, Oh, it's so weird